# How close do you need to be to a lure to discover "lured pokemon"?

Tags: pokemon-go

This is a slightly different question to "How close do you need to be to a poke-stop?"

I want to know if a lured Pokemon at a Pokestop only appear next to the stop if you are within the activation range of it? I sat outside of a Pokestop that I had put a lure on and nothing seemed to appear (by this I mean the pulsing ring around my character doesn't quite reach the ring of the Pokestop). Would this have any effect on me not seeing the Pokemon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on watching [this IGN video](https://youtu.be/z1LPPnIDcpc?t=52s) on how the lures work, it appears that you need to have your player ring intersect with the Pokestops rings to reap the benefit of the lure. If they aren't intersecting in any way, you won't find any lured Pokemon.

Since you said your ring didn't reach the Pokestops, I believe you were too far away.

Comment: Well damn... wasted my Lure Module haha

Comment: I think this is the case. It's confusing because you can be close enough to a Pokestop to place a lure, yet at the same distance not be close enough to get Pokemon encounters.